# Git branch behind remote after rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I'm getting in problems with git.
I wanted to rebase a branch `hotfix` over `master` local and remote, both, so this is what I did.

```
git checkout hotfix
git pull hotfix              #just getting someone changes
git fetch origin master
git rebase origin/master
```

After a long time resolving conflicts and rebuilding project I have it working ok, so I have to upload the changes to the remote branch.

```
git push origin hotfix
```

And this is waht git thinks:

```
$ git push origin login2
To https://name@bitbucket.org/***/***.git
 ! [rejected]        hotfix -> hotfix (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://name@bitbucket.org/***/***.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I have tried:

```
git pull --rebase
```

But this gives same conflicts like before the other rebase and it shoudln't.

I Know I always can do:

```
git push -f
```

But I would preffer to avoid the forced push because I work with another person. I would like to know what I did wrong. I thought that was the way.

PD. I have run `gitk` and it seems there is no reference to the remote `origin/hotfix`, just the local `hotfix` appears.

Thank you!

**Edit:** I guess that when I did the rebase the last commit of the branch change to apply the rebase changes, that was the reason why it had another sha1 commit id. I did a pull overriding my local files.

```
git pull --strategy=ours origin hotfix
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One thing you need to know about rebase is:

Git will change the SHA hashes of every commit not part of the new base branch.

This means there will always be a conflict with the upstream branch after you rebase your local branch and the only way around it is to force push to your upstream.

A common practice is to not rebase commits that have been pushed to upstream. Rebasing is still *okay* if there is only one person working on a branch.

In this case, you don't have an option but to do a force push. In the future it is advisable to keep the working branch for you and your collaborator separate and have a mix of rebase and merge strategies to share your work

Comment: Yes, as I said in my edit I realised that too late. I forget the rule about not doing rebase with pushed commits. I should do a merge. I resolve it merging and overwriting my local files. Thanks, now I will not forget it again.